# String tokenization with nullifying delimiters

Tags: c, tokenize, c-strings

The description for `strsep()` in its man page states that, upon reaching the first delimiter,

> This token is terminated by overwriting the delimiter with a null byte (`'\0'`), and `*stringp` is updated to point past the token.

where `*stringp` is the input string.

I'm wondering if there's any function that will simply update `*stringp` to point past the token without replacement of the delimiter by `'\0'`. I have 3 possible delimiters, which I can input into `strsep()` as `" \t\n"`, so something like `strchr()` which will only search for a single delimiter won't work (not efficiently, at least). Since I need to print out the full string at a later point, I'd otherwise have to perform `memcpy()` in order to print the string at a later point.

(Also, can anyone explain why it's implemented this way..?)

Comment: Is strchr what you are looking for? And what does your question have to do with your title?

Comment: Fixed the title, it was from something else... As for strtchr, that would work, except that I have 3 potential delimiters to search for, which I can input into strsep as `" \t\n"`; strchr only searches for one char. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, unfortunately that would return a length of 0 if the string happened to begin with any of my delimiters; the string consists of user input so the user may input anythign

Comment: I think it is also not a problem to return the length of 0. because it will be processed by the program.(such as `strsep`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of:

```
token = non_nulling_strsep(char** stringp, const char* delims);
```

which is very similar to `strsep`, except that it sets `*stringp` to the delimiter which actually terminates the token, rather than the following character. Unlike `strsep`, that means you can count on `*stringp - token` to be the length of the token, which is useful since the token is not null-terminated, as it is with `strsep`. If there are no more tokens in the string, `*stringp - token` will be 0, so that's the condition you should test to end a token scanning loop.

```
char* non_nulling_strsep (char** stringp, const char* delims) {
  char* token = *stringp + strspn(*stringp, delims);
  *stringp = token + strcspn(token, delims);
  return token;
}
```

You could scan tokens like this:

```
{
  char *end = buffer;
  for (char *token = non_nulling_strsep(&end, " \t\n");
       end - token;
       token = non_nulling_strsep(&end, " \t\n")) {
    printf("Found '%.*s'\n", end - token, token);
  }
}
```

Here's another possible interface, which might well work out better. This one returns the length (0 if there are no more tokens) and sets the string pointer to the start of the next token (the end of the string if there are no more tokens).

```
size_t next_token(char** tokenp, const char* delims) {
  *tokenp += strspn(*tokenp, delims);
  return strcspn(*tokenp, delims);
}
```

With this one, you loop like this:

```
{
  char *token = buffer;
  for (size_t token_len;
       (token_len = next_token(&token, " \t\n"));
       token += token_len) {
    printf("Found '%.*s'\n", token_len, token);
  }
}
```